# Using Pylint to display error and warnings

Tags: python, pylint

So I started using Pylint but since I am using tabs instead of spaces it is giving me as warnings, also since some methods are from base class, that are also as instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'setModel' member while it is has QAbstractTableModel as base class, so how do i set up the Pylint to not consider these things...

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module python.gallery
W:  7, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:  8, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C: 13, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
C: 15, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
W: 15, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 16, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 17, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 18, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 19, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 20, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 22, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 23, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 24, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 25, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 27, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 28, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C: 28, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
W: 31, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 32, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 33, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 34, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 36, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 37, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C: 39, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
W: 39, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 41, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 42, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 44, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 46, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 47, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 49, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 50, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 52, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 53, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 55, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 56, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 58, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 59, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 60, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 61, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 62, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 63, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 64, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 65, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 67, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 68, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 69, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 70, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 71, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 72, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 73, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 74, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 75, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 77, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 78, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 79, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 80, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 81, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 82, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 83, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 85, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 87, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 88, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 89, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 90, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 91, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C: 92, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
W: 92, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 95, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W: 96, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C: 99, 0: Line too long (88/80) (line-too-long)
W: 99, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:101, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:102, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C:102, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
W:105, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:106, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:107, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:108, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:109, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:111, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:112, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:113, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:114, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:115, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:116, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:117, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:120, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:123, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:124, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:125, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:126, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:127, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:128, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:129, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:131, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:132, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:135, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:136, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:137, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:138, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:139, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:140, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C:142, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
C:145, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
W:145, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:146, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:147, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:148, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:149, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C:150, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
W:150, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:152, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:153, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:154, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:155, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:156, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:157, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:159, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:160, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:161, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:162, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:164, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:165, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:168, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:169, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:173, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:174, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:175, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:175, 0: Unnecessary semicolon (unnecessary-semicolon)
W:176, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:178, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:179, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:180, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:181, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:182, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:185, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:186, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:188, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:189, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:189, 0: Unnecessary semicolon (unnecessary-semicolon)
W:190, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C:191, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
W:191, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:193, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:195, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:196, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:199, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:200, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:201, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:202, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:203, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:204, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:205, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:206, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:209, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:211, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:212, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:213, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:214, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C:215, 0: Trailing whitespace (trailing-whitespace)
W:217, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:218, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:219, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
W:220, 0: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces (mixed-indentation)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
W:  3, 0: Relative import 'utils', should be 'python.utils' (relative-import)
F:  4, 0: Unable to import 'PyQt4' (import-error)
C: 17, 2: Invalid attribute name "_thumbRes" (invalid-name)
C: 16, 2: Invalid attribute name "_slideShowWin" (invalid-name)
C:  6, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)
R:  7, 1: Too many arguments (6/5) (too-many-arguments)
C:  7, 1: Invalid argument name "thumbRes" (invalid-name)
C: 22, 1: Invalid method name "colData" (invalid-name)
C: 22, 1: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
W: 22,19: Unused argument 'section' (unused-argument)
W: 22,28: Unused argument 'orientation' (unused-argument)
R: 22, 1: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
C: 27, 1: Invalid method name "headerData" (invalid-name)
W: 27,22: Unused argument 'section' (unused-argument)
R: 27, 1: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
C: 36, 1: Invalid method name "rowCount" (invalid-name)
W: 36,20: Unused argument 'parent' (unused-argument)
C: 41, 1: Invalid method name "columnCount" (invalid-name)
W: 41,23: Unused argument 'parent' (unused-argument)
C: 62, 4: Invalid variable name "fileName" (invalid-name)
C: 71, 4: Invalid variable name "fileName" (invalid-name)
C: 74, 3: Invalid variable name "exifData" (invalid-name)
R: 46, 1: Too many return statements (9/6) (too-many-return-statements)
W: 95,17: Unused argument 'index' (unused-argument)
R: 95, 1: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
C:101, 1: Invalid method name "setData" (invalid-name)
C:109, 4: Invalid variable name "newName" (invalid-name)
W:113, 3: Access to a protected member _renameFile of a client class (protected-access)
E:115, 3: Instance of 'MyListModel' has no 'dataChanged' member (no-member)
R:119, 0: Too many instance attributes (8/7) (too-many-instance-attributes)
C:188, 2: Invalid attribute name "animGallery" (invalid-name)
C:128, 2: Invalid attribute name "__animRate" (invalid-name)
C:146, 2: Invalid attribute name "_twoDLst" (invalid-name)
C:125, 2: Invalid attribute name "_slideShowWin" (invalid-name)
E:123, 1: Use of super on an old style class (super-on-old-class)
C:123, 1: Invalid argument name "imgagesPathLst" (invalid-name)
C:131, 1: Invalid method name "setUpWindow" (invalid-name)
W:136,10: Access to a protected member _browseDir of a client class (protected-access)
E:140, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'setWindowFlags' member (no-member)
E:147, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'setGeometry' member (no-member)
E:148, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'showFullScreen' member (no-member)
E:149, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'setColumnWidth' member (no-member)
E:152, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'setShowGrid' member (no-member)
E:153, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'setWordWrap' member (no-member)
E:154, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'setModel' member (no-member)
E:155, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'resizeColumnsToContents' member (no-member)
E:156, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'resizeRowsToContents' member (no-member)
E:157, 2: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'selectionModel' member (no-member)
C:159, 1: Invalid method name "selChanged" (invalid-name)
C:159, 1: Missing method docstring (missing-docstring)
E:161, 9: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'selectionModel' member (no-member)
E:162,12: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'selectionModel' member (no-member)
C:168, 1: Invalid method name "animateUpSlideShow" (invalid-name)
C:185, 1: Invalid method name "animateUpGallery" (invalid-name)
C:195, 1: Invalid method name "keyPressEvent" (invalid-name)
E:203, 3: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'close' member (no-member)
W:174, 2: Attribute 'animation' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)
W:188, 2: Attribute 'animGallery' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)
W:146, 2: Attribute '_twoDLst' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)
W:150, 2: Attribute '_lm' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)
C:208, 0: Invalid argument name "imgLst" (invalid-name)
E:213, 1: Instance of 'GalleryUi' has no 'raise_' member (no-member)
C:217, 1: Invalid constant name "current_path" (invalid-name)
C:219, 2: Invalid constant name "current_path" (invalid-name)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a **`~/.pylintrc`** file to configure Pylint - amongst other things, this allows you to ignore warnings you don't care about. If you must use tabs, tell Pylint by setting the `indent-string` option to the tab character:

```
[FORMAT]
indent-string=\t
```

Pylint then will only warn you about places where you *mix* tabs and spaces - which you should never do, and keep an eye on in your code.

To disable other warnings, use [Message Control](http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#message-control) to turn them off individually:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
# C0111: Missing docstring
# R0904: Too many public methods
disable=C0111,R0904
```

For getting the IDs for the messages you're interested in, look at the "MESSAGES" section of your Pylint report, or see http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes.

Also see the [Message Control](http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#message-control) section in the Pylint docs, and the respective FAQ entry on [How to find the option name for `.pylintrc` corresponding to a specific command line option](http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#how-do-i-find-the-option-name-for-pylintrc-corresponding-to-a-specific-command-line-option).

I'd really recommend to use a `.pylintrc`, but for the sake of completeness, your other options are:

- annotate your sourcecode with [hint comments](http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message) for Pylint, e.g. `#pylint: disable=W0123,E4567`
- call pylint with the respective command line options, e.g. `pylint --disable=W0702,C0103`

Comment: how do I understand Message id's ?

Comment: @san see my edit. Easiest way is to look the up at http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes

Comment: neat, btw i saved a .pylintrc file in my OSx user directory but I still get messages i set to ignore.

Comment: @san if you want, I can try to help you with that in [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43356/pylintrc-on-os-x)

Comment: get PyQt4 Import error and is it wrong to access rotected member _renameFile of a client class ?

Comment: Notice that pylint 1.0 promote usage of symbolic names rather than numerical ids. They are much easier to read and to remember. To get the symbolic name from the numerical id, try `pylint --help-msg C0111`. To get the full list of messages, try `pylint --list-msg`

Answer (score 1):

For tabs errors with SublimeLinter add:

```
"pep8_ignore":
[
    "W191"
]
```

To:

[sublime data folder]\Packages\User\SublimeLinter.sublime-settings

Bonus, add:

```
"pep8": false
```

To the same file to ignore other pep8 errors like line length.

From the main menu select Preferences > Browse Packages to open the correct folder.

Answer (score 1):

PEP8's ideology is to use 4 spaces for an indentation.

You can tell your code editor or IDE to convert the tabs into spaces blocks.

For example, on Sublime 3:

-check the bottom status bar, click on '*Spaces*'
-a menu pops out, click on "*Convert Indentation to Spaces*"