# Possible To Format A List Without * Magic?

Tags: python, pylint

I wrote some Python code which works but Pylint doesn't like the star. It keeps telling me:

```
Used * or ** magic (star-args)
```

Is it possible to write my code without the star? Some info: I'm using [lxml](http://lxml.de/); self.xml is an [objectified](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) XML file.

```
@property
def version_string(self):
    '''Return the version as a string.'''
    try:
        version_format = self.xml.version.get("format")
    except AttributeError:
        return None
    version_values = (v.text for v in self.xml.version.v)
    return version_format.format(*version_values)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the splat operator. Without knowing what the `version_format` function does, it's not possible to say if you could pass an iterable, or iterate the function directly, but frankly there's no reason to.

Comment: I totally agree, nothing wrong with using argument unpacking to format strings. I'd simply [disable that PyLint warning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20639659/1599111).

Answer (score 7):

If you don't like that pylint warning, disable it. It was originally introduced because having lots of

```
def some_function(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

lowers the readability / maintainability of the code.

Comment: That seems like a bug in their specifications, to catch a splat call, rather than a splat function definition.

Answer (score 4):

*star-args (W0142)* is no longer present in pylint (at least since version 1.4.3). It appears to have been removed fairly recently.