# Pylint to show only warnings and errors

Tags: python, pylint

I would like to use pylint to check my code but I am only interested in error and warning levels. Is there a way to do that in command line or in pylintrc?

I am not interested in filtering given issues (like listing all messages in MESSAGE CONTROL), I just want pylint to ignore **all** convention and refactor messages.

Note: I don't think that's a duplicate of [Using Pylint to display error and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639173/using-pylint-to-display-error-and-warnings)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use the `-d` / `--disable` option to turn off the "C" and "R" message classes (convention and refactor):

```
-d <msg ids>, --disable=<msg ids>
                    Disable the message, report, category or checker with
                    the given id(s). You can either give multiple
                    identifiers separated by comma (,) or put this option
                    multiple times (only on the command line, not in the
                    configuration file where it should appear only
                    once).You can also use "--disable=all" to disable
                    everything first and then reenable specific checks.
                    For example, if you want to run only the similarities
                    checker, you can use "--disable=all
                    --enable=similarities". If you want to run only the
                    classes checker, but have no Warning level messages
                    displayed, use"--disable=all --enable=classes
                    --disable=W"
```

Without the `disable` option (6 convention, 1 refactor, 2 warning, 1 error):

```
$ pylint x.py
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
C:  3, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
R:  3, 0: Too many statements (775/50) (too-many-statements)
W:780,15: Redefining name 'path' from outer scope (line 796) (redefined-outer-name)
C:780, 0: Invalid function name "getSection" (invalid-name)
C:780, 0: Empty function docstring (empty-docstring)
C:782,23: Invalid variable name "inPath" (invalid-name)
W:785, 4: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)
E:785, 4: Undefined variable 'something' (undefined-variable)
C:796, 4: Invalid constant name "path" (invalid-name)
```

After using the `disable` option (0 convention, 0 refactor, 2 warning, 1 error):

```
$ pylint --disable=R,C x.py
W:780,15: Redefining name 'path' from outer scope (line 796) (redefined-outer-name)
W:785, 4: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)
E:785, 4: Undefined variable 'something' (undefined-variable)
```

To set this option in `pylintrc`:

```
disable=R,C
```

Answer (score 21):

```
> python -m pylint --errors-only script_to_validate.py

No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module script_to_validate
E:  7,10: Module 'cv2' has no 'imread' member (no-member)
E:  8,15: Module 'cv2' has no 'threshold' member (no-member)
```

This was tested with Python v3.8 and Pylint v2.11.1.